# I encountered the problem that the execution result of javascript is not as expected

Tags: javascript

Code is as follows：

```
/**
 * this is calculate Timer
 * @param delay Timing steps
 * @returns object Provide calling interface
*/
function countTime(delay = 20) {
    let millseconds = 0,
        seconds = 0,
        timer = null;
    // calculate
    function calculate() {
        millseconds += delay;
        if (millseconds === 1000) {
            seconds += 1;
            millseconds = 0;
        }
    }
    // start the calculate
    function start() {
        timer = setInterval(calculate, delay);
    }
    // end the calculate
    function end() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }

    return {
        start,
        end,
        seconds
    };
}
const obj = countTime();
obj.start();
// Wait for a while to execute
obj.end();
// execute output
console.log(obj.seconds); // always output 0
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?
I really want to know what mechanism is causing javascript, Or is there something missing in my own writing?

Comment: Please add a proper problem/error description in your question and not only two small comments hidden in your script

Comment: _"// Wait for a while to execute"_ - Nothing in your script prevents `obj.end()`/`console.log(obj.seconds)` to execute _before_ the first "tick" of the interval/`calculate`

Comment: add console logs in `start` `calculate` and `end` and things will start to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with the code. First one is that when your function gets executed it returns object with "seconds" property. Unfortunately, that property is not being calculated each time you check against it. So basically it's a stale value. To fix that you can create a new function in your code `getSeconds:

```
function countTime(delay = 20) {
  function getSeconds() {
    return seconds;
  }
  ...

  return {
    start,
    end,
    getSeconds
  }
```

Another issue is that you are not waiting enough time before checking for the seconds. So you should have something like that:

```
const obj = countTime();
obj.start();

setTimeout(() => {
  obj.end();
  console.log(obj.getSeconds());
}, 3000)
```